# How to return value of if else statement in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'd like to return the value of an if else statement in ocaml.

For example, if I do

```
 let myvalue = if my_condition != 0 then do_this else do_this_instead
```

But this doesn't seem to store the result of do_this or do_this_instead in myvalue. If I was doing this in C

```
if(my_condition) 
{
   return 1 + 1;

} else {
   return 1 - 1;
}
```

I want to kind of achieve the same affect, where not only is the if-else logic executed, but there is also kind of like a return value associated with the executed statement that is caught and stored. How might I do this in ocaml?

Comment: I see you are already doing it right, as a psuedo-code of course. How about this, let myvalue = if my_condition then (1 + 1) else (1 - 1);; (assuming my_condition is a boolean value) ... or tell some more so that I can understand the problem you are trying to express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do following...

```
# let myvalue = if 2 > 1 then 2 else 1;;
val myvalue : int = 2
# myvalue;;
- : int = 2
```

What else are you expecting?

`if-then-else` is an expression construct, and expressions produce/have `values`.

Or else, if you looking to call other functions for values in the corresponding `then` and `else` construct, we can try following way...

```
# let my_condition = 2 in
  let do_this () = 1 + 1 in
  let do_this_instead () = 1 - 1 in
  myvalue = if my_condition != 0 then do_this () else do_this_instead ();;
- : bool = true
# myvalue;;
- : int = 2
```